# How can I get suggested 'List' with venues for specific city

Tags: foursquare

There is endpoint for fetching customer's lists https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/users/lists

Is there way to specify city name (location) to choose customer's lists for specific place

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a specific place and see what lists that place appears on here https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/listed

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yea.. but I am interested in lists what contain only venues for the specific place(city). Proposed endpoint returns all list where current venue is mentioned (for example list with venues from different countries/cities) @enc_life